# What is the real size of file?

Tags: file, operating-system

How it is possible that text file has size, which is equal to number of chars inside? For example in file.txt you have string "abc" and size of it is 3 bytes. Everything fine, but what with file icon, filename and file informations? Where these data has been stored?

I checked it on Windows, but at Unix systems situation is probalby the same.

Answer (score 0):

When the file is written to disk, it is by means of low level system call like `write()` and operating systems know exactly how many bytes they write in a given file on a disk. This information, as well as several others (creation and modification date, ownership, etc) is written with the file.

In linux (and generally unix), it is by means of an `inode`that fully describes the file. Informations stored in these `inodes` are:
* access mode
* ids of user and group that owns the file
* size in bytes
* date of creation, modification and access
* list of disk blocks containing file data

These are more or less the informations that are displayed by `ls -l`

You can also see inode number of each file with `ls -i`

You can find [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode) additional details on inodes.

Other informations are coded differently. Names, for instance are only in special files describing a directory, not in the inode. A directory is indeed a list that associate a name with an `inode`.

Icons are generally defined system wide and the association of an icon with a file is done with either filename (and file extension) or with a file "type" that is written in the "`inode`" (or its equivalent in other OS).

Answer (score 0):

Disks allocate space in blocks. Blocks historically were 512 bytes but that has increased over the years so that 4K is common. Your file size will always be a multiple of the block size.

Most file systems (and Windoze does this) allocate disk space in clusters. A cluster is a number of adjacent blocks. Your file size then will always be a multiple of the block size times the cluster factor. This is usually the size of the file as counted by the operating system.

This all depends upon the disk format and the operating system:

> Everything fine, but what with file icon, filename and file informations? Where these data has been stored?

The file information (date, owner, etc.) are usually in some kind of master file table. Sometimes this table will have extensions where information can be stored. Security information is often store in such overflows.

A rationally designed file system will have "A" filename stored in the header. File names are also stored in directories and a file can have multiple names if it is linked to multiple directories. The header file name is used to restored the file in case of corruption.

The location of an icon is entirely system specific and can be done in many ways. In the case of executable files, they are often stored in the file itself. They can also be hidden files in the same directory.